# Using enable_if to match numbers as function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, enable-if

I want to use `std::enable_if` to make constructor that matches numbers. I tried the following code, but the constructor is not found. Main function has examples how I want to use this. What should I change to make this work?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    A(const std::wstring&, const std::wstring&)
    {}

    template<typename T>
    A(const std::wstring& n, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type v)
    {}
};

int main() {
    A(L"n", 1234); // does not compile
    A(L"n", 2.7); // does not compile
    A(L"n", L"n"); // compiles
    return 0;
}
```

Error [on Ideone](https://ideone.com/6Xy1Ti): *template argument deduction/substitution failed*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `T` is not deducible (due to `::type`), one way to go is:

```
template<typename T,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
A(const std::wstring& n, T v)
{}
```